# Setting navigationController instance in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Is there any way to set some object's navigationController by custom?

I mean, without pushing the view into navigationController, I want to set the view's navigationController instance.

I've tried but it says it's read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done using public APIs.

Comment: OK. Then I HAVE TO push the view into the navigationController. Thank you. ;)